# Run connectbot as root?

Tags: networking, remote-control, root-access, ssh

I'd like to do reverse ssh tunneling with my phone. Anyone know how I can run connectbot as root so that it can bind to port 22 ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't run apps that don't request root permissions as root.  This is excluding native apps that you can run from a terminal.

Comment: hmm this sounds strange. Put another way, how can I run an app from the shell? I can su in the shell and then run commands as root. I want to do this: http://www.handlewithlinux.com/android-reverse-ssh

Comment: @barrymac That guide is pretty old and short on details. It doesn't seem like it requires ConnectBot to have root, though.  To run a regular Android app from the shell I believe you do `am start -n full.app.name` where `full.app.name` is something like, for example, `com.google.android.apps.maps` for Google Maps.

Comment: Note that it will run `am` as root, but the app that is started won't have root unless it requests root.

Comment: Yes you're right. I actually got this to work by running quicksshd on a high port and forwarded to that port. So I can finally log on to my phone over ssh from anywhere! Now, why did I want to do this again? :-)

Comment: I should also mention that I still used connectbot to log into the remote server and create the tunnel!